# Firebase deploy - count items in db and assign it

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm making an iOS app and I have this problem now.

I'd like to count the number of unread messages in database and assign it in a database different closure. Like below.

```
exports.arrivalNotifications = functions.database.ref('/trips/{tripId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const data = snap.val();
        const uid = data.uid;

        var counter = 0

        admin.database().ref('/messages/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var childData = childSnapshot.val();
                if (childData.read === false) {
                    counter += 1
                }
            });
        })

        return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', snapshot => {

            const data = snapshot.val();
            const username = data.username

            var payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: username ' has ' + counter + " unread message.",
                    body: 'Press for more'
                }
            }

            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(toUser.fcmToken, payload)
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                    return null;
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                });

            })

        })
```

So I want to use the counter in the payload but I can't find the way to do it. I'm not familiar with JavaScript so if someone can help me I'd appreciate.

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: You're right. But with some help I was able to do what I wanted to do. Thanks for the suggestion anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write your Cloud Function as follow. Please note that I could not test it and it may need some fine-tuning/debugging... especially since it implies chaining several promises.

```
exports.arrivalNotifications = functions.database.ref('/trips/{tripId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const data = snap.val();
    const uid = data.uid;

    let counter = 0;

    return admin.database().ref('/messages/').once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
                const childData = childSnapshot.val();
                if (childData.read === false) {
                    counter += 1;
                }
            });
            return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value');
        })
        .then(snapshot => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            const username = data.username;

            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: username + ' has ' + counter + ' unread message.',
                    body: 'Press for more'
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(toUser.fcmToken, payload);
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            return null;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });

});
```